# What's the most elegant way to enumerate keys on a multidimensional PHP array from the value of a contained element's key?

Tags: php, mysql

Say I have a multidimensional, numeric zero-indexed array that looks like this:

```
$oldArray = (
    0 => array("importantKey" => "1", "otherKey" => "someValue"),
    1 => array("importantKey" => "4", "otherKey" => "someValue"),
);
```

What's the cleanest way to map this to the following, provided I can be sure of the uniqueness of "importantKey"

```
$newArray = (
    1 => array("otherKey" => "someValue"),
    4 => array("otherKey" => "someValue"),
);
```

This is useful when retrieving multiple rows from a database after doing a GROUP BY clause on "importantKey"

Comment: Using a foreach loop and enumerating a new array is the most obvious option to me but I was wondering if there's a PHP specific function for achieving this in a more elegant manner.

Comment: I would say take the most obvious option ! Don't try to be clever :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$newArray = array_reduce($oldArray, function($res, $val) {
    $res[$val['importantKey']]['otherKey'] = $val['otherKey'];

    return $res;
}, array());
```

Is this elegant enought? :)

Comment: Elegant sure enough ! As to understand what's happening, goog luck for the maintainer :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$data=array();
foreach($oldArray as $k=>$v)
{
   if(isset($v['importantKey']) && isset($v['otherKey']))
   {
      $data[$v['importantKey']]=array('otherKey' =>$v['otherKey']);
   }
}

echo "<pre />";
print_r($data);
```

Comment: By experience, it make things easier to use later to keep the important key in the value array. So I would do inside the if :  $data[$v['importantKey']]=$v;

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you define "clean". How about this?

```
$newArray = array_combine(
    array_map(function (array $i) { return $i['importantKey']; }, $oldArray),
    array_map(function (array $i) { return array_diff_key($i, array_flip(['importantKey'])); }, $oldArray)
);
```

This takes a few more iterations than you'd need using a straight forward `foreach` though.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy solution to copy the entire array except the key to an array. Why would you want PK as an array index anyway? A PHP array isn't a database row, and metadata for the array shouldn't be database data.

```
$new = array();
foreach($old as $value) {
    $newInner = $value;
    unset($newInner["importantKey"])
    $new[$value["importantKey"]] = array($newInner);
}
```